# Find sum $ \sum\limits_{k=2}^{2^{2^n}} \frac{1}{2^{\lfloor \log_2k \rfloor} \cdot 4^{\lfloor \log_2(\log_2k )\rfloor}} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Calculate sum
$$ \sum_{k=2}^{2^{2^n}} \frac{1}{2^{\lfloor \log_2k \rfloor} \cdot 4^{\lfloor \log_2(\log_2k )\rfloor}}  $$

I hope to solve this in use of Iverson notation:

### my try

$$ \sum_{k=2}^{2^{2^n}} \frac{1}{2^{\lfloor \log_2k \rfloor} \cdot 4^{\lfloor \log_2(\log_2k )\rfloor}} = \sum_{k,l,m}2^{-l}4^{-m} [2^l \le k < 2^{l+1}][2^{2^m} \le k < 2^{2^m+1}]  $$

and now:
$$ [2^l \le k < 2^{l+1}][2^{2^m} \le k < 2^{2^m+1}] \neq 0 $$ if and only if $$2^l \le k < 2^{l+1} \wedge 2^{2^m} \le k < 2^{2^m+1} $$

I can assume that $l$ is const (we know value of $l$) and treat $m$ as variable depence from $l$. Ok so: 
$$2^l \le 2^{2^m} \wedge 2^{2^m+1} \le 2^{l+1} $$
but it gives me that $l=2^m$
I think that it is not true (but also I don't see mistake). Even if it is true, how can be it finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here  is an answer following  rather closely OP's approach.

> We obtain for $n\in\mathbb{Z}, n\geq  0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=2}^{2^{2^n}}}&\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2^{\left\lfloor\log_2 k\right\rfloor}4^{\left\lfloor\log_2\left(\log_2 k\right)\right\rfloor}}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=2}^{2^{2^n}}\sum_{l,m}2^{-l}4^{-m}\left[l=\left\lfloor\log_2    k\right\rfloor\right]\left[m=\left\lfloor\log_2\left(\log_2\left(k\right)\right)\right\rfloor\right]\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=2}^{2^{2^n}}\sum_{l,m}2^{-l}4^{-m}\left[l\leq \log_2    k<l+1\right]\left[m\leq\log_2\left(\log_2\left(k\right)\right)<m+1\right]\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=2}^{2^{2^n}}\sum_{l,m}2^{-l}4^{-m}\left[2^l\leq    k<2^{l+1}\right]\left[2^{2^m}\leq k<2^{2^{m+1}}\right]\\
> &=\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}4^{-p}\sum_{k=2^{2^p}}^{2^{2^{p+1}}-1}\sum_{l}2^{-l}\left[2^l\leq    k<2^{l+1}\right]+2^{-2^n}4^{-n}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}4^{-p}\sum_{q=2^p}^{2^{p+1}-1}2^{-q}\sum_{k=2^q}^{2^{q+1}-1}1+2^{-2^n}4^{-n}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}4^{-p}\sum_{q=2^p}^{2^{p+1}-1}2^{-q}2^q+2^{-2^n}4^{-n}\\
> &=\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}4^{-p}2^p+2^{-2^n}4^{-n}\\
> &=\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}2^{-p}+2^{-2^n}4^{-n}\\
> &=\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{1-\frac{1}{2}}+2^{-2^n}4^{-n}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{2^n}4^n}}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use *[Iverson  brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* to  get rid of  the floor function.
- In (2) we  use an equivalent representation of the *[floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Equivalences)*.
- In (3) we see the intervals inside the Iverson brackets suggest a partioning of the interval $\left[2,2^{2^n}\right]$. We do a first partitioning with respect to $m$ as union of right half-open intervals and add the value for $k=2^{2^n}$. This way we see $m$ takes precisely one value, namely $m=p$.
- In (4) we continue similarly as we did in (3). This way we see $l$ takes precisely one value, namely $l=q$.
- In (5) we use the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)* formula.

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Comment: @VirtualUser: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let's write
$$\sum_{k=2}^{2^{2^n}} \frac{1}{2^{\lfloor \log_2(k) \rfloor}4^{\lfloor \log_2(\log_2(k))\rfloor}} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{k=2^{2^i}}^{2^{2^{i+1}}-1} \frac{1}{2^{\lfloor \log_2(k) \rfloor}4^{\lfloor \log_2(\log_2(k))\rfloor}} + \frac{1}{2^{2^n}4^{n}}$$

$$= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{k=2^{2^i}}^{2^{2^{i+1}}-1} \frac{1}{2^{\lfloor \log_2(k) \rfloor}4^{i}} + \frac{1}{2^{2^n}4^{n}}$$

Moreover for all $i=0, ..., n-1$, 
$$\sum_{k=2^{2^i}}^{2^{2^{i+1}}-1} \frac{1}{2^{\lfloor \log_2(k) \rfloor}} = \sum_{j=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1} \sum_{k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1} \frac{1}{2^{\lfloor \log_2(k) \rfloor}} = \sum_{j=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1} \sum_{k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1} \frac{1}{2^j}  =  \sum_{j=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1}  \frac{2^j}{2^j} = 2^i $$

You deduce that 
$$S = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^i} + \frac{1}{2^{2^n}4^{n}} = 2 - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + \frac{1}{2^{2^n}4^{n}}$$

Comment: Elegant and concise derivation. (+1)

Comment: Your solution is very clever! Thanks too